# Getting the next key

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var bookCh = {'TOMSAWYER':[Twain,50],
'PARELANDRA':[Lewis,150],
'ROGUECODE':[Russinovich,23],
'WRINKLE':[Lengle,12]};
```

If I match something on ROGUECODE, I want to print the next key to the console (e.g., if I match ROGUECODE, print WRINKLE). Here's what I have to do the match, but I have no idea how to print the next key in the array instead of the current one. If they were numbered keys it would obviously be easy, but they aren't...

```
var currentBook = "ROGUECODE";

for (var bookKey in bookCh) {
 if (bookKey == currentBook) {
  console.log("Next book: " +  ???);
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that Javascript objects are **unordered**. There's absolutely no guarantee that you'll get "WRINKLE" *after* "ROGUECODE".

Comment: Contents of objects cannot be indexed. Convert your object list to an array and All Will Be Well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your array something like this

```
var bookCh = [
  {
    'id': 'TOMSAWYER',
    'meta': [Twain, 50]
  },
  {
    'id': 'PARELANDRA',
    'meta': [Lewis, 150]
  },
  {
    'id': 'ROGUECODE',
    'meta': [Russinovich, 23]
  },
  {
    'id': 'WRINKLE',
    'meta': [Lengle, 12]
  }
]
```

now when you iterate over it

```
for(var i=0; i<bookCh.length-1; i++) {
 // bookCh[i+1] (this is next array item)
}
```

Comment: I ended up coming up with my own solution, but it was pretty similar. I appreciate the sense of this solution, so I'm marking it as correct.

Comment: That needs to be `i<bookCh.length-1` if you always want a next book to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentBook = "ROGUECODE";
var keys = Object.keys(bookCh);
for (var bookKey in bookCh) {
 if (bookKey == currentBook) {
    var curIdx = keys.indoxOf(bookKey); 
    var nextBookKey =  curIdx < keys.length-1 ?  keys[curIdx+1] : null;
    console.log("Next book: " + nextBookKey);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of a hacky way... if you have few keys...

```js
var bookCh = {
    'TOMSAWYER': ['Twain', 50],
    'PARELANDRA': ['Lewis', 150],
    'ROGUECODE': ['Russinovich', 23],
    'WRINKLE': ['Lengle', 12]
};

var currentBook = "ROGUECODE";
var order = {
    'TOMSAWYER': 'PARELANDRA',
    'PARELANDRA': 'ROGUECODE',
    'ROGUECODE': 'WRINKLE',
    'WRINKLE': 'TOMSAWYER'
};

for (var bookKey in bookCh) {
    if (bookKey == currentBook) {
        console.log("Next book: " + bookCh[order[bookKey]]);
    }
}
```